# Why do we add s/es to the verb for third person singular in Simple Present Tense?

Tags: grammar, verbs, present-simple

Simple Present Tense:

> - He catches the bus.
> - She studies English.
> - It runs fast.

Answer (score 1):

Because that is how the English language works. That is how English is defined. That is how everybody uses it (when they speak correctly).